# Is there any *real* solution for taking advantage of multiple cores when running a JUnit/TestNG test suite?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, concurrency, parallel-processing

I know support exists for running JUnit or TestNG test suites in parallel, but it requires specific configuration (such as specifying thread counts, for example) and most importantly do not prevent race conditions in non-thread-safe code.

Are there any tools for the JVM which transparently (ie, without explicit configuration) allocate individual tests to different CPU cores (using different threads in the same process or different processes), while preventing race conditions regardless of thread-safety?

If no such tool exists, what would be the best approach to implement one?

Comment: Several processes would prevent race conditions for sure

Comment: Yes, obviously, but is there are Java-based tool which does that for JUnit/TestNG test suites?

Comment: if would be nice if such parallels test tools could take into account the @ThreadSafe annotation and only run in parallel tests on such classes when they're annotated @ThreadSafe.  I don't think it's a very realistic expectation that said (I don't even know if it's doable).  What about spawning one JVM per core and dividing the tests on each JVM?  I wonder how fast this would be... One thing is sure: it is pathetic to see a 16-cores CPU running a test suite and seeing the CPUs monitor showing only one core active :(

Comment: @Gugussee: It would be nice, but requiring the use of an annotation is not realistic in the general case. Code under test could make use of third-party libraries, or tests could rely on other testing tools (mocking, etc.)... Using separate JVM instances is a valid approach, but might be difficult to implement and add significant overhead. A better approach *might* be to use a custom class loader, which defines a separate copy of each class for each thread in the same JVM instance. I suspect no one ever tried that, though.

Answer (score 0):

My strong suggestion would be to run your tests concurrently with the usual JUnit / TestNG tools.

The reason is simple: **If a test fails due a race condition, then the test has done it's job perfectly** - it has identified a bug in your design, code or concurrency assumptions that you should fix.

Anything that is non-thread-safe that is used simultaneously by multiple test threads (e.g. a mutable static singleton object that is being used on a global basis) is probably a design flaw - you should either make it thread safe or initialise it separately each time as a local object.

Comment: I totally disagree... The OP specifically specified that it may cause trouble in non threadsafe code.  What is your view on all the JavaDoc from the official Java APIs that are documented as non threadsafe?  Do you think someone should rewrite them all so that they'd all be threadsafe?  It is perfectly valid to write non threadsafe code as long as it is documented as such and it is a perfectly legitimate concern the OP has.

Comment: I think you missed the point. I simply want to take advantage of a multi-core CPU to speed up test runs. I am *not* trying to detect race conditions in code not designed for thread-safety.

Comment: just to be clear you wrote *"if a test fails due (to) a race condition, then the test has done it's job perfectly"* and this sentence is totally wrong in the context of the OP's question.  If the code is specified as non-threadsafe, then the test **HAS FAILED MISERABLY** if it fails.

Comment: @Guguessee - nothing wrong with writing non-thread-safe code if as you say it is fully documented, but if you're testing non-thread-safe code then either a) Your test should allocate a local instance itself or b) you should implement locking that serialises access. This is common good practice, and if you do it then you can run all your tests in parallel, safely.

Comment: @Rogerio - sure I understand that, but then you should either a) refactor your tests to create local instances of the non-thread-safe code or b) revisit whatever part of the design is making non-thread-safe code globally accessible without appropriate locking - which is probably a design flaw that you will want to address. I stand by my assertion that the test has done it's job by picking this up! How you fix it is up to you.....